# Serverless Framework Express - Using asynchronous integration error

Tags: asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

So I'm trying to use the [asynchronous integration with REST api gateway setup with Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway#using-asynchronous-integration) -

It says

```
 functions:
  create:
    handler: myHandler
    events:
      - http:
          path: foo/test1
          method: post
          async: true   <-- This will invoke the Lambda return a 200 code but still run the Lambda
```

This however is not happening. When I try to run this offline, I keep getting a `<pre>BadRequestError: request size did not match content length<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd` error. It disappears when I comment out the `async` setting, but works sometimes (all offline)

But once deployed, I can see the 200 return, but the Lambda does not execute at all. I have logs in there, and none of these get triggered.
Any idea on how I can achieve this behaviour? I need to run some long-ish processes, and don't want to make the user wait for a response because of it.

Is this something wrong with this setting? I can't find too much documentation on this, and have been searching for a considerable time. So any help or pointers in the right direction would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Any luck with that? I'm trying to do the same, but getting frustrated :(
I notice that when using the `async: true`, the `integration` changes automatically to `AWS`, as documented. I'm trying to force it to be `proxy`, but no luck.

Comment: @Gurzoni - Unfortunately no, I abandoned this approach and switched to SNS instead.